# Java Intermec ITCScan failed to load

Tags: java, jvm, intermec

I'm trying to implement a Barcode Reader for a CK71 ATEX Intermec Scanner. The operating system is **Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5** and as JVM I'm using **[phoneME Personal Profile](http://davy.preuveneers.be/phoneme/?q=node/10)**. I did install the DC_Java_WM6_Armv4i.cab (see the picture)

[image]

**When I run the code below I get the following error**: `ITCScan failed to load. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ITCScan.dll in java.library.path`

***How can I fix this error?*** **I've tried everything.**

**Note that before, I was using [CreME JVM](http://www.cremejvm.com/#!/page_splash) and everything was working fine.** I gave up CreME when my 30 days evaluation version expired.

The content of the .lnk file (instead of myProject.MainClass are the real names of course):

```
255#"\Program Files\pMEA PP\bin\cvm.exe" "-Xopt:stdioPrefix=\My Documents,useConsole=false" -cp "\My Documents\Trasabilitate.jar;\My Documents\DataCollection.jar" myProject.MainClass
```

Here is the complete code:

```
/*
 * BarcodeSample.java
 *
 * COPYRIGHT (c) 2004 INTERMEC TECHNOLOGIES CORPORATION, ALL RIGHTS RESERVED
 */

import java.awt.*;

import com.intermec.datacollection.*;


/**
 * This sample demonstrates using the BarcodeReader class to
 * read barcode data into a text field.
 */
public class BarcodeSample extends Frame implements BarcodeReadListener
{
    BarcodeReader bcRdr;
    TextField txtFieldData;
    Button btnClose;
    Label  labelStatus;

    public BarcodeSample(String aTitle)
    {
        super(aTitle);
        initComponents();

        try
        {
            bcRdr = new BarcodeReader();
            bcRdr.addBarcodeReadListener(this);
            // Starts asynchronous barcode read
            bcRdr.threadedRead(true);
        }
        catch (BarcodeReaderException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            labelStatus.setText(e.getMessage());
            //*****
            //* Since m_labelStatus was not initialized with text,
            //* doLayout() is required on some platforms in order
            //* to show the new label text for the first setText()
            //* call.
            //*****
            doLayout();
        }
    }

    private void initComponents()
    {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        txtFieldData = new TextField(20);
        add(txtFieldData);
        btnClose = new Button("Close");
        add(btnClose);
        labelStatus = new Label();
        add(labelStatus);

        btnClose.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e)
            {
                exitApp();
            }
        });
        btnClose.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyListener() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                {
                    exitApp();
                }
            }
            public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {}
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {}
        });
    }

    /**
     * This method is invoked when the BarcodeReadEvent occurs.
     */
    public void barcodeRead(BarcodeReadEvent aBarcodeReadEvent)
    {
        /**
         * Uses EventQueue.invokeLater to ensure the UI update
         * executes on the AWT event dispatching thread. 
         */
        final String sNewData = aBarcodeReadEvent.strDataBuffer;
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Displays the scanned data in the text field
                txtFieldData.setText(sNewData);             
            }
        });
    }

    public void exitApp()
    {
        if (bcRdr != null)
            bcRdr.dispose(); // Release system resources used by BarcodeReader
        setVisible(false);
        dispose(); // Dispose the frame
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final BarcodeSample asyncReader =
            new BarcodeSample("Barcode Sample");
        asyncReader.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e)
            {
                asyncReader.exitApp();
            };
        });

        asyncReader.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work. I found out what my java path was using the snippet [here](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/print-all-java-system-properties) (I'll post it below in case something happens to the link):

```
Properties p = System.getProperties();
Enumeration keys = p.keys();
while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
    String key = (String)keys.nextElement();
    String value = (String)p.get(key);
    System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
}
```

**And then I added my ITCScan.dll to the folder where java.library.path was set (in my case, \ProgramFiles\pMEA PP\bin.**

I don't know if this is the most elegant solution, but it works. Hope it'll help somebody someday.